# How can I add the curl `-H` param in form?

Tags: forms, http, curl

There is a Linux curl example of HTTP request:

```
 curl https://api.paypal.com/v1.3/transactions/qrcode \
-H "Authorization: Bearer <TOKEN>" \
-d amount=100 \
-d currency="USD" \
-d reference="jsd342113" \
-d ipn_url="http://demowebsite.com/ipn"
```

Now I want to concert to form.

I know how to convert the `-d` params, but I don't know how to concert the `-H` param.

```
<form method="post" action="http://demo/api/x"> 
  <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="100"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="currency" value="USD"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="reference" value="jsd342113"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="ipn_url" value="http://demowebsite.com/ipn"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Pay Now" /> 
</form>
```

but how can I add the `-H` param in form?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to add HTTP request header in a form, but you can use ajax for replace it.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately, custom headers have to be done with javascript/XMLHttpRequest, not with `<form>`'s. something like

```
<div id="myform">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="100" />
    <input type="hidden" name="currency" value="USD" />
    <input type="hidden" name="reference" value="jsd342113" />
    <input type="hidden" name="ipn_url" value="http://demowebsite.com/ipn" />
    <input type="submit" value="Pay Now" />
    <script>
        document.querySelector("#myform > [type=submit]").addEventListener("click", function() {
            var all = document.querySelectorAll("#myform > input");
            var inputs = new FormData();
            for (var i = 0; i < all.length; ++i) {
                inputs.append(all[i].name, all[i].value);
            }
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("POST", "http://demo/api/x");
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer <TOKEN>");
            xhr.send(inputs);
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

now please send a complaint to the W3C about the lack of header control in `<form>` posts.